# PHP not performing INSERT to MySQL on form post

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a product spec form add to a table called ProductSpecs on post, however despite the same synatx working fine for SELECT does not work for INSERT. The permissions to the MySQL account used allow full read/write, and I am able to insert into the database via console input using the same request.

Any ideas will be most appreicative.

```
 $sql = " INSERT INTO ProductSpecs (SpecID, Code, ProductName, Barcode, ProductDescription, SKU, CYear, HeaderStyle, Certification, InnerQTY, OuterQTY, PackagingDescription, Comments) VALUES (NULL, '$Code', '$ProductName', '$Barcode', '$ProductDescription', '$SKU', '$CYear', '$HeaderStyle', '$Certification', '$InnerQTY', '$OuterQTY', '$PackagingDescription', '$Comments')"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Thanks

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like checking if the query actually succeeded? You don't say WHICH db library you're using, but probably `$result` will be a boolean FALSE indicating failure.

Comment: Check for the last error... What does it say?

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. What database layer are you using? If it supports prepared statements with placeholders, make a point to use those whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to regard SpecID in your query. It should be auto increment not null value, so don't regard it and it will work fine.

Comment: it's not necessary, but it's also not WRONG to have it in the query. inserting null directly into an auto_increment field is a perfectly valid method of getting an auto-inc id generated.

Comment: I think this is applied in the mysql console well, but what about other sql executing extensions that may deal with the Null string in different or not standard ways.

Comment: no. php doesn't know what sql is. it has no idea what "null" in a string means. `$foo = 'null'` and `$foo = null` are two ENTIRELY different things. doesn't matter WHERE the sql comes from. it's sql.

Answer (score 1):

You want to try and write your code with prepared statements and you can choose PDO or MySQLI. Here is an example how to do it with PDO. Also I would look at this link it might help you. http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements/ along with these videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvxid3DoLjE.

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "test123";
$db_name = "test_db";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tests(name1, name2, name3, name4,name5,name6, name7, name8, name9, name10) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST["name1"]);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST["name2"]);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST["name3"]);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST["name4"]);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST["name5"]);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $_POST["name6"]);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $_POST["name7"]);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $_POST["name8"]);
$stmt->bindParam(9, $_POST["name9"]);
$stmt->bindParam(10, $_POST["name10"]);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: This example is if you have a form with these field names and you want the form to insert the data into the database. Not sure if this will help. I am new to PHP with PDO, so I can only pass along what I have learned so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting columns names inside ``

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ProductSpecs (`SpecID`, `Code`, `ProductName`, `Barcode`, `ProductDescription`, `SKU`, `CYear`, `HeaderStyle`, `Certification`, `InnerQTY`, `OuterQTY`, `PackagingDescription`, `Comments`) VALUES (NULL, '$Code', '$ProductName', '$Barcode', '$ProductDescription', '$SKU', '$CYear', '$HeaderStyle', '$Certification', '$InnerQTY', '$OuterQTY', '$PackagingDescription', '$Comments');"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

if fails echo last error message and comment.
the `SepcID` may have been set as not null which may cause the problem.

Comment: None of the field names are reserved words, so this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try not referencing your ID column?

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO ProductSpecs (Code, ProductName, Barcode, ProductDescription, SKU, CYear, HeaderStyle, Certification, InnerQTY, OuterQTY, PackagingDescription, Comments) VALUES ('$Code', '$ProductName', '$Barcode', '$ProductDescription', '$SKU', '$CYear', '$HeaderStyle', '$Certification', '$InnerQTY', '$OuterQTY', '$PackagingDescription', '$Comments')"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql)
```